# Load a component on data receiving Angular

Tags: angular

Just thinking is it possible to load a component when data is loaded inside a service,
For Example: in my service
 i have a method which receives the data, after that, a component should get loaded 
**Service**

```
setFormValue(data)
{
  this.FormDetails.push(data);
  this.colValuelg = colvaluelg;
  this.colValuemd = colvaluemd;
  this.colValueg = colvalueg;
  console.log(this.colValueg,"awd",this.colValuelg,"trrtrt",this.colValuemd);

  // I now want to load a component here
  // because there is a specific task on constructor and ngOninit of that component
}
```

I tried by creating an object of that component but, I don't want to do it because,  in that component, I may need a DI at the constructor.

Comment: you could try to navigate to the page you need?

Comment: no navigation bro , i knw dat way is there

Comment: why would you want to load a component if you dont want to navigate?

Comment: I want to load a component once my data is received I dnt want to load it before the data is received

Comment: so you can navigate, once you have the data, navigate to the component

Comment: but is there another option apart from router

Comment: not to load it correctly, no

Answer (score 2):

You could navigate to the new component only when you function is resolved.

something like this: Define a new route in your routes

```
var Route = {
    path: '',
    component: YourComponent,
    resolve: { data: service.setFormValue()},
},
```